# How can I convert columns to rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have something like this:

```
Values     Time
  22        0
  45        1
  65        2
  78        0
  12        1
  45        2
```

and I want this:

```
Time    0    1    2 
Val1    22   45   65
Val2    78   12   45
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is `pivot` creating the index with `cumcount`

```
df['idx'] = 'Val' + (df.groupby('Time').cumcount()+1).astype(str)
df.pivot(index='idx', columns='Time', values='Values').rename_axis(None)
```

Output:

```
Time   0   1   2
Val1  22  45  65
Val2  78  12  45
```

Comment: @HugoB Yes, pivot is very useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe is a very informative post, though it does not cover the index creation step, required to solve your question fully.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll use it for sure! So kind!

Answer (score 1):

You need to transpose your array/matrix.

Use

```
list(map(list, zip(*l)))
```

where list is your list

Answer (score 1):

If your time-delta is constant, ordered and has no missing values:

```
DELTA = 3
new_values = [df['Values'].iloc[i*DELTA:i*DELTA+DELTA].values.transpose() for i in range(int(len(df)/DELTA))]
df_new = pd.DataFrame(new_values , index=['Val'+str(i+1) for i in range(len(new_values ))])

print(df_new)
         0   1   2
Val1    22  45  65
Val2    78  12  45
```

Not a pretty solution, but maybe it helps. :-)